# How to show a loading Indicator if I have a user location error in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, geolocation

I don't know how to show a loading indicator if I have a user location error, and then when I obtain again the location not show the loading indicator.

Here is my code:

```
  async loadingIndicator () {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      message: 'error, we are getting your location...'
    })
    await loading.present()
  }

  ionViewWillEnter () {
    this.watchId = this.gpsService.watchPosition((location) => {
      this.userLatitude = location.coords.latitude
      this.userLongitud = location.coords.longitude
      console.log('User location: ', location)
    },
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 60_000, maximumAge: null }
    )

  }

  updateLocation (location, err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('updatelocation err: ', err)
      this.loadingIndicator()
      return
    }
    console.log('updateLocation', location)
  }
```

Comment: You should use toast when an error occurred not a loader.

Comment: Please post complete code not just fragments. There is not enough here to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ion-spinner : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/spinner with a boolean condition.

on your **TS** file :

```
isLoading = false; //the boolean you activate when you need to show a spinner
  
// I suppose it's somewhere here you want to activate the loading

  updateLocation (location, err) {
if (err) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  console.error('updatelocation err: ', err)
  this.loadingIndicator()
  return
}
this.isLoading = false;
console.log('updateLocation', location)
}
```

On your **html** file

```
// where you need to show the spinner
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
  <ion-spinner name="circles"></ion-spinner>
</div>
```